# How can I play an entrance theme transition without navigating the frame?

Tags: winui-3

In my application, one of my pages consists solely of a WebView2. Navigating to the page resets the WebView2. Even with NavigationCacheMode set to required. So I put the WebView2 page into it's own persistent frame and manually hide and show the frame as the user navigates in the NavigationView.

The WebView2 no longer gets reset however the page transition doesn't run because I don't navigate to the frame.

Is there a way to manually run the page transition or is there an animation that achieves the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to manually run the WebView2 page transition without navigating the frame. You could try to realize the animations as you like and then integrate the animations into your app.

For more details, you could refer to the Doc:[Animations in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/xaml-animation)

Comment: Haven't heard from you for a while. Have you got any updates about this issue? Could you please check my answer?